# Creating model of disc with offset hole for 3D printing

Tags: 3d-printing

For an engineering project I have been requested to 3d print a disc with the following characteristics:

- 7.5 cm diameter
- 4.8mm thickness
- hole with a diameter of 1.27 centimeters through the disc and offset from the center by 1.905 centimeters

The modeling software available to me is Blender, and we are exporting the model to a .stl for use with the MakerBot Replicator 2X. I have never used Blender or this printer before, but was able to create a model of the shape I require without too much difficulty and export it to the printer.

I have however come across many problems with how the printer builds my model, depending on adjustments I make in Blender and in the printer settings:

- It will create a solid disk with no hole but with ample honeycomb support inside, which is what I desire
- It will create a disk with a hole and all of the proper dimensions but omits support structure inside, leading to the printer being unable to properly print the top part of the disk.
- Only fragments of the model make it into the final product.

I have linked [the .stl file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8yLWnJwm3OEQVc1ckxjNC1Fa0k/view?usp=sharing) I am currently working with. If anyone has experience with either of these programs and could take a look at the file and explain the issue to me, I would appreciate it. Like I said, I'm new to these softwares and the printer, so I'm sure it's a small thing I missed.

Answer (score 4):

I just had a look at the file and I can see disconnected geometry around the top and bottom rings:

[image]

Trying creating it in a similar fashion to this:

Add a circle mesh and select ***Nothing*** on fill type.

[image]

***Tab*** to go into edit mode.  Select all by pressing ***A***.  Press ***E*** to extrude and press ***Enter*** without moving the mouse.  Press ***S*** to scale in toward the center.  Then select the new hole and offset it by the proper margin.

[image]

Select all (***A***) and extrude again in the ***Z*** direction this time.  You now have a hole with faces:

[image]

Another way to do this with a little more precision is with the knife tool (you can find tutorials on this forum).  But after you make your cut, and delete the faces, you must ***Bridge Edge Loops*** by pressing ***W***:

[image]